# Transparent images have weird black edges

Tags: texturing, transparency, image

I'm using geometry nodes to scatter a partially transparent grass image around a plane, and getting weird black parts in the background. Here's what it looks like:

[image: my grass render]

this is one of the grass images im using: [image: grass image]

anyone know how to fix it?

(also this is my first time using stack exchange, hope im doing this right lol)

Comment: Hello, in the Render panel > Light Paths > Max Bounces > try to increase the Transparent value

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH <3

Comment: Please use the search function here as well... [Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects). See my second answer there with further explanations. The accepted answer unfortunately talks about Transmission bounces, while this is actually a problem of Transparent bounces and so the accepted answer is actually wrong. My same answer is also here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275682/png-image-black-only-when-in-front-of-other-objects/275691#275691

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Render* panel > *Light Paths > Max Bounces* > increase the *Transparent* value.